# Image from array not showing the correct result

Tags: python, image, grayscale

I'm generating binary configurations of a lattice and I want to save them as B&W images. I'm using the following code on Python 3.7:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

L = 10
s = 2*np.random.randint(2, size=(L, L))-1
s = (s + 1) * 255/ 2
s.astype(np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(s, mode = 'L')
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

img.save('test.jpg')

img2 = Image.open('test.jpg').convert('L')
data = asarray(img2).astype(int)
print(data)
```

This is the random array I have generated:

```
[[255.   0.   0.   0.   0. 255. 255.   0.   0. 255.]
 [  0.   0.   0. 255.   0. 255.   0.   0. 255.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0. 255. 255. 255.   0. 255.   0. 255.]
 [255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255.   0. 255. 255. 255.]
 [255. 255.   0.   0.   0.   0. 255.   0. 255.   0.]
 [255. 255.   0.   0. 255.   0. 255.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0. 255. 255.   0. 255. 255.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0. 255.   0. 255.   0. 255. 255.   0. 255.   0.]
 [  0. 255.   0.   0. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255. 255.]
 [  0. 255.   0.   0. 255.   0. 255. 255.   0.   0.]]
```

But the code outputs a totally different image from the one I was expecting. The result I get is the following image that doesn't seem to have anything to do with that array:

[obtained image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OXcb.png)

while I would expect this

[expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeXSv.png)

which I got from visualising the array in Mathematica. Notice that, at the end of the code, I save and retrieve the image. When I retrieve it as an array, I obtain

```
[[  0   3   0  11   0 216 106  67   0   3]
 [  0   5   0  10   2   7   7   0   0   1]
 [  2   0   7   0   0   1   0   0   1   0]
 [ 10   0   0   3   8   0   8  14   3   3]
 [  0  12   0  21   0 219 111  43   0   0]
 [  4   8   0 206 114  86   0  15   1   1]
 [  0   0  22   0   8   0   0   7   7   0]
 [  6   0   0   9   0   8   6 221 102  81]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

which is completely different from the original array s. I would appreciate if someone could indicate to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the colormap used by `plt.imshow`. By default it will display grayscale images with colors from dark blue to bright yellow. Try adding an optional parameter, called [cmap](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

```
plt.imshow(img ,cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That solves the problem of plotting it on grayscale, but what I am actually worried is the fact that the image is not binary as the array. While the array has only two values, 0 and 255, even the grayscale plot for img has more than two values. I am editing the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- you saved it as a JPEG which is lossy - it is allowed to alter your pixels to save space. If you care that pixels are accurately saved, use a lossless format such as PNG
- you didn't save the effect of changing the `dtype`, so the variable you used was still a float - I annotated it in code below

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Generate random but repeatable lattice
np.random.seed(42)
L = 10
s = 2*np.random.randint(2, size=(L, L))-1
s = (s + 1) * 255/ 2
sA = s.astype(np.uint8)     # <--- YOUR CODE GOES WRONG HERE

# Now make into "PIL Image" and save as lossless PNG (not JPEG)
imA = Image.fromarray(sA)
imA.save('result.png')
imA.show()

# Now load back from disk
imB = Image.open('result.png')
sB  = np.array(imB)
imB.show()

# Check we get the same Numpy array
if np.allclose(sA, sB):
    print('Arrays are equal')
else:
    print('ERROR: Arrays differ')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I changed the extension of the file to PNG and the same thing happens. Is there any other modification I need to add to the code apart from JPG -> PNG in the file extension?

Comment: I have updated my answer now that I have had time to check your code more thoroughly. Please have another look.

Comment: I understand the error. It's working fine now. Thanks a lot!